# how to manage locks to prevent a duplicate insert

Tags: mysql

I am trying to cache an aggregation but due to concurrency could run into a referential integrity violation..

Here is what I am doing (sort of boiled down a bit) :

```
select  low, high
into    l_low, l_high
from    nasd_stats
where   symbol_id = l_symbol_id;

if( l_low is NULL ) then 
      select  max(last),
              min(last)  
      into    l_high, l_low
      from    nasd
      where   symbol_id = l_symbol_id;

      insert  into nasd_stats values ( l_symbol_id, l_low, l_high );
end if;
```

So, two users could run the sproc that has this code, and so detect, at the same time, that l_low is null, and then both try and insert into nasd_stats at the same time after the min/max aggregation (one of which would fail as there is a unique key on nasd_stats based on symbol_id).

Any idea how to prevent that from happening??

I'm guessing I could do this :

```
Start Transaction;
delete from nasd_stats where symbol_id = l_symbol_id;
insert into nasd_stats values ( l_symbol_id, l_low, l_high;
Commit;
```

logic being, the delete would lock the row (even if it doesn't exist), and then the insert would do what I want to do.

TIA.

Don

Comment: [`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)

Comment: there are two tables involved.  I can't select on one and lock the second that is not involved in the select ... can I?

Comment: No, but `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` will lock the first table to prevent concurrent queries obtaining `low` and `high` until the lock is released (upon committing the transaction).

Comment: ok so I should 1) Start Transaction; 2) select max(last) from nasd FOR UPDATE; 3) insert into nasd_stats values (...); 4) Commit;

Comment: actually no - correct that.  I would have to do the FOR UPDATE on the select on nasd_stats.  right?  This is the first sql statement in my example code.  NOTE : a row not existing is a boundary case.  It most likely will be there (all day).  the problem is inserting that first row into nasd-stats for symbol_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the key is defined on symbol_id  field then execute the query in following manner

```
insert  into nasd_stats Select  distinct l_symbol_id, l_low, l_high  from nasd_stats where not exists (Select 1 from nasd_stats where symbol_id  = l_symbol_id) ;
```

Comment: thx interesting suggestion - combing insert & not exists in one statement.  If I understand correctly, this would guarantee that only one row is ever inserted for unique key symbol_id?  first guy sees 'not exists' and inserts.  concurrent guy his insert doesnt go thru.  that would be fine, the usual case is that a row exists, it is only at start-up it does not.  TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just check for the symbol ID in your insert and it it exists then someone already got to it so you dont need to do another insert?

So your code would be the same but the insert statement would be

```
  insert  into nasd_stats values ( l_symbol_id, l_low, l_high ) where symbol_id =    l_symbol_id AND l_low is NULL ;
```